# What is the best way to use composite components for columns of data table?

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have two composite components with `<h:dataTable>` inside and they are differ only by content of a few `<h:column>` What is the best way to escape copy-paste with possibilities of composite components? I know about tags, but we have no any tag in my project. So, it's not solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute to your composite component:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="columnType" type="java.lang.String" required="true" />
</cc:interface>
```

Then in the implementation

```
 <h:column rendered="#{cc.attrs.columnType eq 'typeAColumns'>
     #{data.valueForColumnTypeA}
 </h:column>
 <h:column rendered="#{cc.attrs.columnType eq 'typeBColumns'>
     #{data.valueForColumnTypeB}
 </h:column>
```

You can then use it like

```
 <my:compositeTable columnType="typeAColumns"/>
 <my:compositeTable columnType="typeBColumns"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but then I will mix a few implementations inside the one component. Today I have only two implementations, tomorrow three. What then? 
I'll get the enormous component, which will be hard to maintain. It's not ok.
As far I understand that there is no best way to use composite components for reusing of dataTable. I have to use tags or rendered attribute or do copy-paste. By my opinion it's bad ways. I hope that in the future we will get something from JSF Team.